# How to use websolr with Apache Solr module? (D7)

Tags: 7, search

I´ve got a Drupal 7 site and I would like to use apache solr.

Is there any way to connect [websolr](http://www.websolr.com) to that module? Haven´t found any module to do that (ie. as the Acquia module).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Solr presents a generic API, and you should be able to use any search module which uses Solr with Websolr. We tend to recommend the [Apache Solr Search Integration](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module.